# Upgrading from font awesome 4 to pro 5 with angular ..icons not showing up

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5, font-awesome-4, angular-fontawesome

I was trying to upgrade from `font awesome 4` to `5` . I was following [this link](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4)
I removed the `font awesome 4` package : `npm uninstall font-awesome` 
and then added a `npmrc` file containing this code in the root of my project as described in their documentation [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers):

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=<My_token>
```

and then installed the plugin : `npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro`

and in  `angular.json` file I added this code :

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/fontawesome.css",
 ...]
```

I thought that every thing is set. but when I tried to render some icons by typing `<i class="far fa-acorn"></i>` in my html ..the icon where not displayed.

could someone please tell me what I'am missing in my configurations?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found it..
it was just to import `all.css` file instead of `fontawesome.css` in `angular.json` file 
my bad !